# Laptop built-in monitor not detected, dual GPU

Tags: drivers, ati, display, hardware

The built-in monitor of my laptop seems to be not recognized by Ubuntu. The screen is black though illuminated. External monitor connected through HDMI works just fine. Doesn't matter if plugged in during bootup.

My laptop is Samsung 670Z5E (AMD HD8850M + integrated Intel GPU). It runs Ubuntu 14.04 installed alongside Windows 8.1.  I've installed proprietary driver and Catalyst Control Center from AMD website but it's made no difference.

What might be the issue?

Here's result of `lshw -c display`:

```
  *-display               
       description: Display controller
       product: Venus XT [Radeon HD 8870M / R9 M270X/M370X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7d00000-f7d3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7d40000-f7d5ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

And `xrandr -q`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     72.0     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Edit: Here's `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "amd-layout"
    Screen 0 "amd-screen" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "amd-device"
    Driver "fglrx"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "amd-monitor"
    Option "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amd-screen"
    Device "amd-device"
    Monitor "amd-monitor"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: You have both intel and amd driver in xorg. If you want amd then blacklist intel driver.

Comment: Hi. The amd driver is the one that's operating now, at least that's what I get from `lsmod | grep fglrx` and `fglrxinfo`. I should have specified that previously I only had Intel driver and it was working with the same flaw. Also, blacklisting Intel doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by switching from UEFI to UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: What do you mean ?